# Passing Location in Object as Variable

Tags: javascript

I have a large object, mixed with arrays of data (it's a treeview of folders and images - I have no control over what is outputted here.

For example:

```
var test = {
   Folders: [{
      Folders:[{
         Folders:[{
            Folders:[
               {value:1},{value:2}
            ]
         }]
      }]
      },{}
   ]
}
```

Value 1 (which in my case is an image) can be found here:

```
test.Folders[0].Folders[0].Folders[0].Folders[0].value
```

My end users are using a drop down to select their folder, I need to somehow pass the location via the drop down.

I've tried adding the "path" to the data-attr attribute of the drop down:

```
<option value="folder6" data-attr="[0].Folders[0].Folders[0].Folders[0]">Folder6</option>
```

However attempting to use that like this:

```
var myLocation = $('#element').find('option:selected').attr('data-attr');
//myLocation now is a string "Folders[0].Folders[0].Folders[0].Folders[0].value"
console.log(test[myLocation]
```

Doesn't work (it's down to the Arrays and numbers as passing a string as an object location in this fashion normally works).

I'm quietly confident I'm going about this the wrong way fullstop. I'm open to ideas on how better to do this in general, or how to get this horrible fudge to work.

Comment: According to your example, Even `test[Folders[0].Folders[0].Folders[0].Folders[0].value]` doesn't work. May be something like this happened to your real code? a kinda typo or order/scope error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this issue and it mostly depends on your needs and global architecture.

**#1 The Evil Way (using eval)**

```
var path = '[0].Folders[0].Folders[0].Folders[0]';
eval('test.Folders' + path); //Object {value: 1}
```

**#2 Use an object as a map to index every folder**

```
var foldersMap = {};
//loop over your tree and build the index
foldersMap[path] = folder;

//then retrieve it later
foldersMap[path];
```

**#3 Store the object on the option directly**

```
//while building the option
optionEl.folder = folder;

//then later retrieve it from the selected option
yourSelect.options[yourSelect.selectedIndex].folder;
```

**#4 Create your own keypath function that can traverse an object structure based on a string keypath rather than using eval. I will provide an implementation as soon as I have more time.**

There are probably many other ways, but these are just ideas.

Comment: I was going to suggest #3.  You're already storing the "path", you might as well just reference that part of the object directly.  Nothing saying all your references to the object have to point to the root.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually a tree can be n-levels deep.  Baking in the path like that may not be a good ideas unless you know how "deep" the structure will be ahead of time.

It looks like you might be trying to show each potential folder in a drop down list (or maybe just the ones with images).

To do this, I would create a function to recursively loop through your json structure.  The result of this function would either directly build the drop down menu or flatten the values into an array which could then be bound to the drop down menu.  I would use a front-end templating library like handlebar.js, but you could also manipulate a dropdown control via JQuery.

Comment: I've got the recursive loop fine, and I display every Folder in the drop down, my problem is once the user selects a certain Folder, I need to know where in the Tree that folder lives.

Comment: Cool, now I understand.  Yea executing the value in the data-attrib will just give you the "object".  What about using a variable in your recursive structure to keep tabs on where you currently are in your folder structure (a string variable).  Set the Data-Attrib value this string variable.  string path = "/", first recursion -> path = "/Folder1", second recursion -> path="/Folder1/Folder2/"

Answer (score 0):

Try storing it as a JSON array in `data-attr`. jQuery will pull it out as an array. Then you just need to find a way to loop it. Here's my first crack at it (with no validation and exception handling)...

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option data-attr="[0,0,0,0]">Foo</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
var test = {
    Folders: [{
        Folders: [{
            Folders: [{
                Folders: [{
                    value: 1
                }, {
                    value: 2
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {}]
};


var folderIndexes = $("option").data("attr"); // an array

alert(getValue(test, folderIndexes));

function getValue(folders, folderIndexes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < folderIndexes.length; i++) {
        folders = folders.Folders[folderIndexes[i]];
    }
    return folders.value;
}
```

Fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/atn22/